# Error 401 (Unauthorized) IdentityServer 4 y ServiceFabric (5 nodos)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure

Tengo implementado el Identity Server 4 y el service fabric, ambos en 5 nodos lo que hace que la sesión se pierda, ya que el nodo que creo el token no es el mismo que lo valida.

Intenté solo usar una instancia del IdentityServer con lo que solucioné una parte del problema (consultar información del token), pero de igual forma al intentar usar cualquier controlador del service fabric me saldrá en la mayoría de las veces 401, ya que a menos que el nodo que responda sea el mismo que creo el token, saldrá el error 401. ¿Alguna solución?

Ejemplo del startup de la API

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("Data").GetValue<string>("TenantsURL");
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ApiName = Configuration.GetSection("Data").GetValue<string>("ApiName");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la  misma configuración que tu, solo que por ahora tengo service-fabric on-premise (y en un las proximas versiones ya tendria que hacer deploy en Azure)

Son varios microservicios (la mayoria .NET Core), uno es el de Auth con IdentityServer4.

Tenemos en 1 y 5 nodos las pruebas.

**Pero siempre atrás de un Reverse-Proxy**

Asi los clientes solo acceden a un solo endpoint (url de las API) e internamente el Reverse-Proxy realiza al consulta a la aplicacion dentro del Service Fabric. Y **siempre es a traves de un solo endpoint** no importa el nodo que responda.

Por esa razón, siempre accedemos con el mismo host y puerto al servicio de auth.

Y en la propiedad Authority de AddIdentityServerAuthentication coloco el endpoint del reverse proxy

```
...options.Authority = "[endpoint-reverse-proxy-con-auth]"
```

Como todavía no lo tengo en Azure no lo tengo configurado, pero alli deberias hacer [realizar con Azure Load Balancer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#reaching-microservices-from-outside-the-cluster) para mapear.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Reverse proxy in Azure Service Fabric](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia